# Non-stop automatic right click glitch in chrome-based browsers on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: ubuntu, wayland

I've recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 23.10, dual booted on a Xiaomi laptop alongside Windows 11.

Every time I switch to Brave or Google Chrome from any other window, especially another workspace, there is a constant auto-right click that doesn't go away. Clicking anywhere on the screen doesn't solve the problem. Pressing Esc or F4 when it happens stops it until the window is focused the next time. [Screen Recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A1LRbotJj71V0UrdZ2YgZV9F2AbjTaOo/view?usp=drive_link) for reference.

This issue is random and doesn't happen every time. I can't figure out what triggers this or how to replicate it. Also it's always happened on Wayland and not on Xorg.

Is this some bug/hardware compatibility issue or something else?